# If a query misses an index, why is the row_number over () in an effectively random order?

Tags: postgresql

Here is a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/626cc2/2
Tested in 9.6 and 10.2

But in case that isn't preferred, the schema and query are:

```
CREATE TABLE events("id" varchar(36), "ts" timestamp);
CREATE INDEX events_default_order ON events(ts DESC, id DESC);
INSERT INTO events("id", "ts") VALUES
    ('dccc3a43-8a48-4c29-84e5-906b7817d9a4', '2019-05-20 11:46:19'),
    ('f7355c58-1e09-4043-b4ee-fb3d3d997ac7', '2019-05-17 20:05:01'),
... -- 50 or so rows
;
```

-- In this query, the window function using an empty OVER returns out of order numbers.

```
SELECT id
     , ts
     , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ts DESC, id ASC) AS row_num_good
     , row_number() OVER () AS row_num_bad
FROM events
WHERE (ts > cast('2019-05-10 14:20:13-0400' as timestamptz))
ORDER BY ts DESC, id ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

-- But this one gives both lists in order.

```
SELECT id
     , ts
     , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ts DESC, id DESC) AS row_num_good
     , row_number() OVER () AS row_num_is_now_good
FROM events
WHERE (ts > cast('2019-05-10 14:20:13-0400' as timestamptz))
ORDER BY ts DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` there is no particular order, or in other words **any** order is the correct one. You already seem to know how to fix this: Explicitly use `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as sticky mention if you don't specify an order then any order is a good order. And you cant assume anything even if in previous result you get the order you want. Change in hardware, db version, index or data can change that result.

In this case because

```
CREATE INDEX events_default_order ON events(ts DESC, id DESC);
```

The data is retrieve based on the index order there for is already order and the row_number is perform in an order set. But again that can change if for a different query the db engine decide use a different index instead or the data is move to a raid disk.

If you DROP the index you will see the exact same result.

Also if you change the index to:

```
CREATE INDEX events_default_order ON events(ts DESC, id ASC);
```

You will get the inverted behaviour

Comment: I thought that windowing functions were evaluated last, but they are evaluated before the order by clause of the select.  I found a nice recap of the order of operations here: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/